# How to increment angular repeater?

Tags: angularjs

I've an array of of images and an array of columns.
array of images has 20 images.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="image in images">
   <div data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
      <div class="row1">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{image}}">
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{image}}">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I increment image position everytime an image is used?
I mean, every `col in cols` iteration `image` will take the same index for both rows. I need:

```
row1 = image[0], 
row2 = image[1], 
row1 = image[2], 
...and so on.
```

Comment: Why do you need outer ng-repeat if you just want to access the image array you can do it in cols ng-repeat itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need outer `ng-repeat` as per your requirement. Try this if it helps.

```
<div data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
  <div class="row1">
   <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{images[2*$index]}}">
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
   <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{images[2*$index+1]}}">
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to keep the outer loop then you can try this alternate solution

```
<div data-ng-repeat="image in images" ng-init="imageIndex = $index">
   <div data-ng-repeat="col in cols">
      <div class="row1">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{images[2*imageIndex]}}">
      </div>
      <div class="row2">
       <img class="img-responsive" width="100%" src="{{images[2*imageIndex+1]}}">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can also access the outer `ng-repeat`'s $index using `$parent.$index`

Comment: Thanks, it was close. But i think i need the outer ng-repeat for my purpose, so $index is refering to inner repeater at this point, maybe a $parent could solve?

Comment: `$parent.$index` should work to get the outer `ng-repeat`'s $index

Comment: I may forgot to say, `imageIndex` should be incremented before it usage. OR, index should be incremented on repeater itsel(?). Otherwise instead of 10 times, reapter will do the 20

Comment: You can change the logic as per your requirement. But if this has helped you solve your problem the you can accept this answer.